# How to render a new message without re-rendering previous messages in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to add a new message from the form.js component into the message array which is in App.js, and mapping over through it to render that message.

But each time I add a new message all other messages in the array also get re-render, Due to these, it creates a performance issue as if I want to add the 100th message then all other 99 messages also get re-render with the 100th message.

undesired output photo:-

[As you can see the console image I mapped over through the messageArr array to render message 4 but all other messages 1, 2, 3 also getting render with message 4 I want other messages on UI but they should not get re-render with the current message which is message 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/575oI.jpg)

Any solution for this like only the added message should get render?

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
const [messageArr, setMessageArr] = useState([]);

const addMessage = (messageText) => {
    setMessageArr([...messageArr, messageText]);
};
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {messageArr.map(({ id, message }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                    <li>{message}</li>
                    {console.log(message)}
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <Form addMessage={addMessage} />
    </div>
)};
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = ({ addMessage }) => {
const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = {
        id: v4(),
        message: messageText
    } 
    addMessage(newMessage);
    setMessageText('');
};

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
            type='text'
            value={messageText}
            onChange={(e) => setMessageText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Add message</button>
    </form>
)};
```

Comment: why is one `key` = `v4()` and the other `key` = `v4`?  is `v4 a function`?

Comment: yes I have edited the key part still rendering previous messages

Comment: So? Any feedback from you, Vijay?

Answer (score 0):

Because `setMessageArr([...messageArr, messageText]);` is adding new message but not removing the previous messages .All that you need to do is: `setMessageArr([messageText]);`

Edit:The console.log(message) is showing multiple messages,you are setting the values correctly but you are not testing the values correctly.whenever you want to test some value(the updated value which you want to see) always test the changes using an useEffect ,in your case like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(messageArr)
  },[messageArr]);
```

instead of doing console.log for any value here and there ,instead put it inside a useEffect.You will see the correct results when you will do it like this,remove console.log from the div part of App.js and test the way i have suggested you to.

Comment: But I want all other messages to be seen like whats-app when we send our message then all upper messages not lost they are still there just new message gets added down

Comment: can you post a Screenshot of the undesired output that you are getting?

Comment: I have added undesired output please have look

Comment: try doing simply this `{messageArr.map((message) => (
                <div >
                    {console.log(message)}
                    <li >{message}</li>
                </div>
            ))}`

Comment: I tried what you say but still all other messages also getting re-render with the current message they should only render once and be on UI.

Comment: that is strange cause i tried this approach and it worked fine on my local.just try then what @vigor has suggested.

Comment: ohhh wait,do one thing try displaying it inside the Form.js itself by moving `const [messageArr, setMessageArr] = useState([]);` to Form.js and see if that works.

Comment: or better post your code on codesandbox and share the link here so i can debug it.

Comment: add the code of app.js nd form.js there.It's missing!

Comment: Please have a look at the link and open the console

Comment: in the link that you have shared no code is present in Form.js and App.js is not having the code that you have pasted on stackoverflow.so update it and share the link of the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the v4() function do? I think the problem is maybe it is a random value generator, so every time there is change in the message data, the key is changed and make react re-render all of the previous message.

If that is the case, try to use message id for your key so if there is new message added, react will recognize the ids of the previous message and won't re-render the previously rendered message

```
{messageArr.map((message) => (
  <div key={message.id}>
    <li key={message.id}>{message}</li>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: hey, vigor I have updated what you say but still, previous messages are rendering with the current message and that v4() is to generate a new id each time.

Answer (score 0):

This WORKS !

In React, a Child is re-rendered when Parent is re-rendered only when `shoudComponentUpdate` in Child returns true, which is true by default. (Talking about a class-based Child)
So, i suggest:

1. Create a separate component for the message item
2. Implement the `shouldComponentUpdate`, which receives the `nextProps` as param
3. Compare `nextProps`: if they are the same as current `props`, return `false`, else `true`
4. This way, only the new message will be rendered

Also important: do not forget the `key`

Comment: can you send the codesandbox link where I can see the code. I am still not able to resolve it.